# CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt (rosbuild_init): Unknown CMake command "rosbuild_init"

Tags: ros, bashrc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I faced this error, while trying to operate **cmake .. -DROS_BUILD_TYPE=Release** in the build folder of ROS Path.
Does anyone know how to solve it ? Here is the my ROS Path in .bashrc file:

```
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=${ROS_PACKAGE_PATH}:/home/ramtin/ORB_SLAM2/Examples/ROS/ORB_SLAM2
```

And here is the Error :

```
ramtin@ramtin:~/ORB_SLAM2/Examples/ROS/ORB_SLAM2$ mkdir build
ramtin@ramtin:~/ORB_SLAM2/Examples/ROS/ORB_SLAM2$ cd build
ramtin@ramtin:~/ORB_SLAM2/Examples/ROS/ORB_SLAM2/build$ cmake .. -DROS_BUILD_TYPE=Release
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.5
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.5
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:4 (rosbuild_init):
  Unknown CMake command "rosbuild_init".


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/ramtin/ORB_SLAM2/Examples/ROS/ORB_SLAM2/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
ramtin@ramtin:~/ORB_SLAM2/Examples/ROS/ORB_SLAM2/build$ make -j
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236517/cmake-error-at-cmakelists.txt-(rosbuild_init):---unknown-cmake-command-%22rosbuild_init%22/) by [ramtinkr](https://answers.ros.org/users/27111/ramtinkr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-06-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When you're using rosbuild you do not directly invoke cmake. Please see the documentation at http://wiki.ros.org/rosbuild

As linked at the top you build using [rosmake](http://wiki.ros.org/rosmake)

There's a [tutorial for building a package](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/BuildingPackages) Click on the rosbuild toggle to get the rosbuild version.

If you're not familiar with ROS I'd suggest at least reading through the [core tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials).

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2016-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1